# Mono.TextTemplating.Roslyn T4 pass parameter

Tags: c#, .net, t4

I would like to pass a value/ parameter to a .tt file. In this case, it's the 'ClassName'.
To generate the class, the Mono.TextTemplating.Roslyn NuGet package is used and .NET 6.

As soon as the .tt is executed, the next error is displayed:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter
> 'objectToConvert')

Both 'Add' functions don't result in the expected behavior:

```
session.Add("ClassName", "ABC");
generator.AddParameter(null, null, "ClassName", "ABC");
```

What is the correct way to pass a value and use it within the .tt.

.tt file

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
//----------------------------------------------------
//
// THIS IS AN AUTO GENERATED FILE.
//
//----------------------------------------------------

using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class <#= ClassName #>
    {
            
    }
}
<#+
public string ClassName { get; set; }
#>
```

tt execution:

```
string inputFile = @"C:\MyClass2.tt";
string outputFile = @"C:\ClassA2.cs";
var generator = new Mono.TextTemplating.TemplateGenerator();
var session = generator.GetOrCreateSession();

session.Add("ClassName", "ABC"); // does NOT work    
generator.AddParameter(null, null, "ClassName", "ABC"); // does NOT work

generator.ProcessTemplate(inputFile, outputFile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Parameter is not exposed as variables, they are intended as arguments for custom directive processors. To access directly from code you have to set `hostspecific="true"` and access via `Host.ResolveParameterValue (paramName)`.

`*.tt` file:

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="true" #>
<# string temp = this.Host.ResolveParameterValue("", "", "foo");#>
```

```cs
string inputFile = @"D:\Project\App\MyClass2.tt";
string outputFile = @"D:\Project\App\ClassA2.cs";
var generator = new Mono.TextTemplating.TemplateGenerator();
var session = generator.GetOrCreateSession();

session.Add("ClassName", "TTT");
generator.AddParameter(null, null, "ClassName", "TTT");

generator.ProcessTemplate(inputFile, outputFile);
```

Add `hostspecific="true"` attribute to template element as follows:
`MyClass2.tt` :

```
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="true" #>
<# string Myclass = this.Host.ResolveParameterValue("", "", "ClassName");#>

using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class <#= Myclass #>
    {
            
    }
}
```

output `ClassA2.cs` :

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class TTT
    {
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help! `this.Host.ResolveParameterValue` is the key to resolve the issue which I was experiencing.